# string or binary data would be truncated issue with a function

Tags: sql, vb.net, t-sql

So I have a function which is able to generate and ID for the user called CustomerID. This is the function that I am using right now

```
Private Function GenerateID() As String
        SqlCon = New SqlConnection(conString)
        Dim value As String = "0000"
        Try

            SqlCon.Open()
            SqlCmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Customer ORDER BY ID DESC", SqlCon)
            SqlDR = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            If SqlDR.HasRows Then
                SqlDR.Read()
                value = SqlDR.Item("ID")
            End If
            SqlDR.Close()
            value += 1
            If value <= 9 Then
                value = "000" & value
            ElseIf value <= 99 Then
                value = "00" & value
            ElseIf value <= 999 Then
                value = "0" & value
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            If SqlCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                SqlCon.Close()
            End If
        End Try
        Return value
    End Function
```

And the in other method I will call it like this:

```
Sub auto()
        Try
            txtID.Text = GenerateID()
            txtClienteID.Text = "C-" + GenerateID()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

I found that the problem comes from this line: `txtClienteID.Text = "C-" + GenerateID()`, then if I remove the GenerateID() like this `txtClienteID.Text = "C-"` it will gives me error to. Now, if I remove the - and do this `txtClienteID.Text = "C"` it will actually work.

The error that is always displays is

> string or binary data would be truncated

The datatype on database for the CustomerID is nvarchar(50)

So do you have any ideia about this?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of the question you asked yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38330247/string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-the-statement-has-been-terminated-vb-n

Comment: It is the same question with a different issue

Comment: What line throws the error when you debug? Why is the ID-column nvarchar if you use it as a number? If it was number you could just use database to auto-increment the value on insert and this method would be obsolete. Also value-variable is string and you are using it as integer, it's not pretty. AND use String.PadLeft...

Comment: No no. The ID Column is int...

Comment: You should let the database do its job and auto-increment the Id for you - that is its job.  The Q says Id is nvarchar, but then in comments you say it is int.  Also, the query is flawed to start with an your code is leaking.